# DNS error when switching to new VPC and subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

We have one hosted zone in Route 53 to handle the majority of our public domain names. Most of these point to an ELB, all of which are on the same VPC.

Recently we decided to do some reorganization of security groups and have decided to move all of our staging instances to a staging VPC and keep all of production on production.

However when I go to point `stg.autobrain.com` to the staging ELB it returns a `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error. Everything is similar to how it was previously except for it being on a different VPC as far as I remember.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS misconfiguration.  Have you tested resolution with `dig`?  Or the [test tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-test.html)?  There are three possibilities  of failure (either one fails or both fail), which suggest 3 different problems.

Comment: It turns out I had to change the security group on the ELB. One of the SGs it was whitelisting was on the old VPC.